# FatSecret Rest API Throwing Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest

I am trying to implement FatSecret REST API but while assessing Food.search getting Error, not able to understand is it App implementation error on Server Error.

Request URL : GET

```
 NSString *endpoint= @"https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?&format=json&language=en&max_results=50&method=foods.search&oauth_consumer_key=9d*********&oauth_nonce=52A2E&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1500756883&oauth_version=1.0&page_number=0&region=US&search_expression=r&oauth_signature=CvB%2F52z7c2T7******%3D"

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:endpoint];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        //
        if (data) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse  = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                //PERFORM YOUR OPERATIONS
                NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"%@", json);
            }
        }else if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Errorrrrrrr....");
        }

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Response:

```
{ "error": {"code": 1, "message": "An unknown error occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." }}
```

Please help, let me know What I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance